# How to incorporate size data with shape in stereographic morphometrics?

Tags: morphology, morphometry

This may be an extremely simple point that I am missing, but how are you supposed to know the exact size of a structure being analyzed in three dimensions? When doing two dimensional morphometrics, you simply have a scale bar with your image. I know that microCT and some other methods may do this automatically, but some are now using free software like 123D Catch from Autodesk to create mesh models. In this case, are you strictly restricted to shape independent of size? If not, how do you add in a 3D scale bar, so to speak?

Comment: A cube of known dimensions in your field of view would suffice.

Comment: But can I then set the scale in these programs just as I would using a 2D ruler? How does the actual calibration occur with the object in view? None of the programs I've looked at using (tps, landmark, R, etc...) seem to have a way to do this.